# Google PieChart - Adding Animation on Creation

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I want to create a [Google Pie Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart?hl=en).

What I want to have is have a fancy animation on creating the chart when the page first loads. What I have tried is this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart()
    {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
      ['Work',     11],
      ['Eat',      2],
      ['Commute',  2],
      ['Watch TV', 2],
      ['Sleep',    7]
      ]);

      var options = {
        title: 'My Daily Activities',
        is3D: true,
        animation:
          {
            duration: 1000,
            easing: 'in',
          }
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="piechart_3d" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

More specifically, it is:

```
animation: {
  duration: 1000,
  easing: 'in',
}
```

But it is not working.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

animation is not supported on Pie charts

see *Valid Chart Types* in the table under [supported-modifications](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/animation#supported-modifications)